# How to redirect a request in Dart/shelf?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-shelf

I'm using `shelf` in Dart to setup a simple web server. How can I redirect a request from `/` to `/oauth2callback` in the example below?

I have found [this method](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-io/HttpClientResponse/redirect.html), but somehow I cannot compile the code even though I import `dart:io`.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart';
import 'package:shelf_router/shelf_router.dart';

final router = Router()
  ..get('/', rootHandler)
  ..get('/oauth2callback', oauth2callback);

Response rootHandler(Request req) {
  return Response.ok('Hello, World!\n');
}

Response oauth2callback(Request request) {
  return Response.ok('Redirected!\n');

}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  final _handler = Pipeline().addMiddleware(logRequests()).addHandler(router);
  final server = await serve(_handler, '0.0.0.0', 8080);
  print('Server listening on port ${server.port}');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send a 302 response like this:

```
Response rootHandler(Request request) {
  Map<String,String> headers = {'location':'/oauth2callback'};
  return Response(302,headers:headers);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use standard Shelf methods:

```
return Response.movedPermanently(newUrl); // generates 301
```

or

```
return Response.found(newUrl); // generates 302
```